# Google Map not working in Jquery Tool Overlays modal dialog

Tags: google-maps-api-3, overlay, jquery-tools

I am using jquerytools(http://jquerytools.org/) for the overlays modal dialog in my site. Now i have to show google map in modal window(jquery tool layover), but unfortunately google map is not loaded in overlay.

What i am doing is just showing a complete form in Overlay(using ajax request, i got complete html for the form"that includes google map as well" and render it in layover). In my case its not loading the google map but other form elements are rendered successfully. I have open that page(that i fetch via ajax request to show in overlay) in separate tab and then it shows proper elements with google map as well.

It seems to me that google maps are conflicting with jquery tools layover.

Anyone else stuck in the same problem or any idea for its solutions. Thanks in advance.

NOTE: I am not talking about google maps overlay. My issue is showing google maps in overlay modal dialog

Comment: The basic problem you are describing seems clear, but we can't help you if you don't include some code, a link to your page, or setup a jsFiddle that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I haven't found any useful reply about my post related to jquery overlay moadl dialogue with google maps in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through internet i found that showing google maps in overlay modal dialogue using ajax request is not a way. I use iframe and it resolved my issue. Now i use iframe and google map is loaded at page load time and it works perfectly fine for me. If anyone can suggest a way to do it via ajax request then i would consider that way probably. As far as i searched on internet iframe would be best option in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

I followed the link you give above (event-in-town.com/place/index/addlocationlayover), which you say loads the map fine, but I don't see a map when I load that page. One thing I see - there is a problem in the URL that loads the map:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;language=&amp;region=DE">
</script>
```

The correct parameter to define the language for your map is: `&amp;language=DE`, so start by changing your map load URL to:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;language=DE">
</script>
```

That should get you moving in the right direction -

Comment: Now i have added language parameter correctly...but still map is not loaded :(